# Problems using api auth with Google Calendar JS API

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I'm working on a small website that can do stuff with the Google Calendar API.  I've posted it over here:  http://evansiroky.com/temp-gcal-question/tests/  Whenever I try to authorize, it doesn't seem to matter what clientId I use, it always says it is authorized.  Also, it doesn't seem to matter if immediate is set to true or false.  Here is the authorization code:

```
gapi.auth.authorize({ 
  client_id: clientId, 
  scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'], 
  immediate: immediate
}, function(authResult) {
  if(authResult && !authResult.error) {
    isAuthorized = true;
  } else {
    isAuthorized = false;
  }
  if(callback) {
    var out = isAuthorized ? null : authResult;
    callback(out);
  }
});
```

However, once I try to list events of a calendar, I get a dailyLimitExceededUnreg error.  Here is the code for listing events:

```
gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function() {
  var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list(_.extend({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    orderBy: 'starttime',
    singleEvents: true, 
    showDeleted: true,
  }, options.data));

  request.then(function(resp) {
    options.success(resp);
  }, function(reason) {
    options.failure(reason);
  });
});
```

And here is the error that is returned:

```
{
  "result": {
    "error": {
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "usageLimits",
          "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
          "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
          "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
        }
      ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
    }
  },
  "body": "{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\": \"usageLimits\",\n    \"reason\": \"dailyLimitExceededUnreg\",\n    \"message\": \"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.\",\n    \"extendedHelp\": \"https://code.google.com/apis/console\"\n   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 403,\n  \"message\": \"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.\"\n }\n}\n",
  "headers": {
    "date": "Fri, 02 Oct 2015 19:08:41 GMT",
    "content-encoding": "gzip",
    "server": "GSE",
    "vary": "Origin, X-Origin",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "cache-control": "private, max-age=0",
    "content-length": "215",
    "expires": "Fri, 02 Oct 2015 19:08:41 GMT"
  },
  "status": 403,
  "statusText": "OK"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 403 usagelimits error is thrown generally when your application is exceeding daily limits. Did you check your daily quota of your application? you can check on your developers console. Also, are you implementing exponential back for your application https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors

Comment: Nothing is showing up for usage, neither errors nor success.  It's like nothing is getting through.